# Spinlock metric: latency and delay difference

Tags: operating-system, multiprocess

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3usmMQMDX0

In the video above, the latency is described as "time to acquire a free lock", the delay(waiting time) is "time to stop spinning and acquire a lock that has been freed". These descriptions are a little vague for a learner.
Could you please help me to elaborate the difference of these terms?

I googled them, but could not find a good explanation.